# Using USB A to B cable for projector

Tags: usb, display

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 since one week with an HDMI display TV and everything is working. I'm using raspbian os.

I have an Epson EB S9 projector. I used to project using my Windows laptop through USB A to B cable. A driver was auto installed for Windows. However no such support is available from Epson for Linux.

How do I project using Raspberry Pi in such a scenario? Is it possible to output video through usb? Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: what other inputs are available on the projector, S-video? HDMI? DVI?

Comment: @SteveRobillard it has vga and s video. But no HDMI.

Comment: You don't mention which model Pi you have, but places like thepihut.com sell HDMI to VGA adapters and with the right cable you can get s-video out either through the dedicated connector on early Pi models or using a 4 part audio and video cable for later models like the Pi3. The VGA adapter is likely to provide better quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This projector [doesn't seem to be supported via USB](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2109960) even in mainstream Linux distributions like Ubuntu, let alone Raspbian. Like Steve said, your best bet is an [HDMI to VGA converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=HDMI+to+VGA+converter).